# find the determinant of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

let $A= [a_{ij}]$ $n×n$  where $n > 2$  be a square matrix with integer entries . let $A$ be

a non singular . if $|A|$ denote the determimant of $A$ and $C_{ij}$ denote the $(i,j)$th

cofactor      .If $|A|$ divide the $C_{ij}$  for all $1\le i,j\le n$ ,then

1.$|A| =  \pm1$

2 No such $A$  exist

3.$|A|$ may be interger  other then  $\pm1$

4.$|A|= 1$

i was  using cramer rule...by cramer rule option 1  is correct...i don't know  the other option,,,pliz help me or give me  some hints  or pliz  show  me the right direction,,,i would be more thankful...thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let's consider identity, diagonal, triangular matrices to exclude some cases.

- (2) counter example is A=I
- (4) counter example is A diagonal n-by-n matrix with n odd and
  +1,-1,.. along the diagonal
- (3) since each element of A is divisible by $|A| \implies |A|=\pm1$
- (1) is true

Comment: +1 thanks  @gimusi....if i will take  orthogonal matrix    which is a diagonal matrix,,,and det A= +-1........here  i don't know to exclude some cases in triangular matrix ,,can u elaborate more?

Comment: e.g. if you consider A=I, what about (2)?

Comment: ok,,,i got  @gimusi it that mean   option 1,3 and 4  are correct am i right ?

Comment: The aim is to find counter examples to exlude some answer. So what about option (2) if A=I?

Comment: if A= I then |A|= 1, then A is exist  so option 2  is not correct@gimusi

Comment: Exactly! |A|=1 and 1 divides every integers (zero included).

Comment: ok @gimusi...that  mean 1,3,4 are correct  am I right ?

Comment: Now consider a diagonal n-by-n matrix with n odd and +1,-1,.. along the diagonal. What about (4)?

Comment: ok @gimusi  |A| = -1...SO OPTION 4 WILL NOT CORRECT  am i right ?

Comment: thanks  a  lot @gimusi  i got it...

Comment: You are welcome. I think the correct one is the first!

Comment: @ gimusi can u elaborate for option 3....?